# ¿Como hacer correctamente una funcion que retorne una promesa con Ionic?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, promesas, ionic3

Quiero hacer una función que me devuelva una promesa, pero no domino muy bien el tema, lo que he intentado es esto

```
MiFuncion(miParametro: string): Promise<void>{
    // mi codigo ...
    console.log(miParametro)
    return new Promise (function( resolve, reject){
        resolve()
     })
 }
this.MiFuncion('Probando').then(()=>console.log('esto funciono corretamente')).catch((err)=>console.log(err))
```

Esto estaría bien?

Comment: Deberias mejorar tu pregunta, luego de implementar esto que te retorna, que esperas que te retorne, si te aparece un error, podrias colocarlo?

Comment: Intuyo que no es una pregunta específica de ionic, más bien de javascript o typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes incluir todo el código (o al menos el código asíncrono por el cuál requieras usar una promesa) dentro de la función parámetro de tu promesa. Me imagino que en contexto de ionic sería algo así:

```
@Component({..})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.miFuncion('hola', 'mundo').then(..);
  }

  miFuncion(param1, param2): Promise<any> {

    /** 
     * Fíjate que acá debes usar un lambda en vez de una función
     * anónima, de lo contrario el contexto de 'this' va a ser el de la 
     * función que le pasas a Promise, y no el 'this' de FooComponent 
     */
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      /** 
       * En este caso, obtengo el resultado de otra función para usarlo
       * dentro del cuerpo de mi promesa
       */
      const saludo = this.miOtraFuncion(param1, param2);

      if ( saludo === 'hola mundo' ) {
        /**
         * 'Hola mundo que hace' es entonces el valor que va a recibir
         * el primer callback en .then(), en caso de que se cumpla 
         * la condición
         */
        resolve('Hola mundo que hace');
      } else {
        /**
         * Este mensaje irá en el segundo callback de .then, o bien
         * puedes capturarlo al final con .catch()
         */
        reject('Mal educado');
      }
    });
  }

  miOtraFuncion(param1, param2): string {
    // realiza algún proceso
    return param1 + " " + param2;
  }
}
```

Veamos ahora como puedes encadenar promesas y el comportamiento general de `then()` y `catch()`:

```
@Component({..})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.miFuncion('hola', 'mundo').then(
      // El primer callback se ejecuta si la promesa fue resuelta con resolve()
      (success_msg) => {
        /** 
         * Lo bueno de las promesas, es que si retornas cualquier valor
         * dentro de uno de sus callbacks, puedes seguir encadenando
         * promesas con then()
         */
        console.log(success_msg); // "Hola mundo que hace"
        return this.servicio.getAlgo(); 
      },
      // El segundo callback se ejecuta si la promesa fue resuelta con reject() 
      (error_msg) => console.log(error_msg); // "Mal educado"
    )
    .then(
      (data) => {
        // el valor de data lo que retorna la llamada a this.servicio.getAlgo()
        return "kittenRequest";
      }
    )
    .then(
      (value) => console.log(value); // "kittenRequest"
    )
    .catch(
      // En .catch() vas a capturar cualquier error que haya salido en la cadena 
      // de promesas de no haber sido manejado por el segundo callback de then
      (error) => {
        // Haz algo con el error
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Como puedes ver, una vez dentro de una cadena de promesas, puedes orquestar la secuencia de procesos en el orden que quieras.

Si quieres aprender más al respecto, te recomiendo el siguiente workshop gratuito de NodeSchool aunque está en inglés como puedes ver, [Promise It Won't Hurt](https://github.com/stevekane/promise-it-wont-hurt)

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta puesto q no veo la necesidad de retornar una promesa como resultado, yo mas bien creo que en tu caso lo que quieres hacer es poder secuenciar varias promesas para lograr cierto comportamiento en secuencia. Si ese es tu objetivo lo que podrías intentar crear todas las promesas y luego mandarlas a ejecutar en cadena, lo voy intentar ilustrar, sera algo mas o menos asi:

```
var prom1 = Prom1(req, res).then(function(resul1) {
        Prom3(req, res).then(function(resul2){
            Prom3(req, res).then( function (resul3) {
                if (resul3) {
                    ProcesarAlgo(resul3);
                } else {
                    console.log("paso algo");
                }               
            })
        }); 
    }).catch( function (errorDB) {
        console.log("------------------------ERROR------------------");
    });
```

Dentro del then de cada promesa puedes recuperar un valor que ya sea un conjunto de datos o un tipo boolean que puedes mandar para la siguiente promesa o procesarlo de la forma que prefieras ya sea con in if o lo que tu necesites. Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Realmente lo que quiero hace es saber como se hace declarar un función que cuando la use pueda hacer lo que hace la siguiente función: firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification(correo).then(()=>{
    console.log('he ha enviado el correo correctamente');
   }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log('a fallado el envio del correo, el error es : ' + error);
    
   });

Comment: Amigo esa no es la mejor forma de encadenar promesas, de hecho cae en las malas prácticas del callback hell.